# Ansible: How to get duplicate items from list?

Tags: ansible

How can I get duplicated items in ansible

**Input:**

```
- vars: 
    list1: 
      - a
      - b
      - c
      - d
      - d
      - e
      - e
      - e
```

**Expected output:**

```
list1: 
  - d
  - e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Count the frequencies in a loop. For example,

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list2: "{{ list2 + [{'key': item,
                             'freq': list1|
                                     select('regex', myregex)|
                                     length}] }}"
      loop: "{{ list1|unique|sort }}"
      vars:
        list2: []
        myregex: "^{{ item }}$"
```

gives

```yaml
  list2:
    - {freq: 1, key: a}
    - {freq: 1, key: b}
    - {freq: 1, key: c}
    - {freq: 2, key: d}
    - {freq: 3, key: e}
```

Then select the items. For example, use *json_query*

```yaml
  list3: "{{ list2|json_query('[?freq > `1`].key') }}"
```

, or the combination of the filters *selectattr* and *map*

```yaml
  list4: "{{ list2|selectattr('freq', '>', 1)|map(attribute='key') }}"
```

Both options give the list `[d, e]`

---

- The next option is the comparison of items by [Extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables). For example,

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list5: "{{ list5|default([]) + [item] }}"
      loop: "{{ list1|sort }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: yes
      when: item == ansible_loop.nextitem|default('')
```

Then, `list5|unique` gives the same result `[d, e]`

---

- The simplest option is the filter [community.general.counter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/counter_filter.html#ansible-collections-community-general-counter-filter)

```yaml
  freq6: "{{ list1|community.general.counter }}"
```

gives the dictionary

```yaml
  freq6: {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 2, e: 3}
```

Select the duplicates

```yaml
  list7: "{{ freq6|dict2items|selectattr('value', '>', 1)|map(attribute='key') }}"
```

gives the same result

```yaml
  list7: [d, e]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    list1: [a, b, c, d, d, e, e, e]

    list3: "{{ list2|json_query('[?freq > `1`].key') }}"
    list4: "{{ list2|selectattr('freq', '>', 1)|map(attribute='key') }}"

    freq6: "{{ list1|community.general.counter }}"
    list7: "{{ freq6|dict2items|selectattr('value', '>', 1)|map(attribute='key') }}"

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        list2: "{{ list2 + [{'key': item,
                             'freq': list1|
                                     select('regex', myregex)|
                                     length}] }}"
      loop: "{{ list1|unique|sort }}"
      vars:
        list2: []
        myregex: "^{{ item }}$"
    - debug:
        var: list2|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: list3|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: list4|to_yaml

    - set_fact:
        list5: "{{ list5|default([]) + [item] }}"
      loop: "{{ list1|sort }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: true
      when: item == ansible_loop.nextitem|default('')
    - debug:
        var: list5|unique|to_yaml

    - debug:
        var: freq6|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: list7|to_yaml
```

Answer (score 3):

Looping in ansible throught large data lists can be very slow. It is much faster to create a custom_filter.

In your project root create folder **filter_plugins**.
Inside the folder create a python file (custom_filter.py for example)
Then use the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {'duplicates': self.duplicates}

    def duplicates(self, items):
        sums = {}
        result = []

        for item in items:
            if item not in sums:
                sums[item] = 1
            else:
                if sums[item] == 1:
                    result.append(item)
                sums[item] += 1
        return result
```

Then call the custom filter in your playbook:

```
    - name: "debug"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 1] | duplicates }}"
```

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        2,
        1
    ]
}
```

When you are processing data it is usually better to use custom filters.