# Comparing two list after passing through Ansible map('regex_replace')

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to compare 2 lists to get the difference and also duplicates. Example:

```yaml
- name: Debug
  hosts: "localhost"
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  vars: 
    list1: 
      - {name: aBC_SOMEITEM-A01_dEF, type: random, policy: one}
      - {name: aBC_SOMEITEM-A02_dEF, type: random, policy: two}
      - {name: aBC_SOMEITEM-A03_dEF, type: random, policy: three}

    list2: 
      - {name: "SOMEITEM-A01", type: "random", policy: "one"}
      - {name: "SOMEITEM-A02", type: "random", policy: "two"}
      - {name: "SOMEITEM-A03", type: "random", policy: "three"}
      - {name: "SOMEITEM-A03", type: "random", policy: "three"}
      - {name: "SOMEITEM-A04", type: "random", policy: "four"}

    list3: "{{ list1 | map('ansible.builtin.regex_replace', 'aBC_|_dEF', '') | list }}"

  tasks: 
  - debug: 
      msg: |
        {{ list1 | to_yaml(default_flow_style=none) }}
        {{ list2 | to_yaml(default_flow_style=none) }}
        {{ list3 | to_yaml(default_flow_style=none) }}

        {{ list2 | difference(list3) | to_yaml(default_flow_style=none) }}
```

`list3`'s output after the `map('regex_replace')` filter looks like this:

```yaml
['{''name'': ''SOMEITEM-A01'', ''type'': ''random'', ''policy'': ''one''}', '{''name'':
    ''SOMEITEM-A02'', ''type'': ''random'', ''policy'': ''two''}', '{''name'': ''SOMEITEM-A03'',
    ''type'': ''random'', ''policy'': ''three''}']
```

1. How do I normalize list3 so that the resulting output of the difference is

```yaml
- {name: SOMEITEM-A04, policy: three, type: random}
```

2. `list2` has a duplicate dict, how can I find the duplicate? E.g

```yaml
- {name: "SOMEITEM-A03", type: "random", policy: "three"}
```

I was looking at both answers from here but couldn't figure it out - [Ansible: How to get duplicate items from list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60828923/ansible-how-to-get-duplicate-items-from-list/70948690#70948690)

(I don't mind writing custom filter plugins to accomplish this as the data set can be very large)

Comment: There is no `name: SOMEITEM-A04`, `policy: three` item in *list2*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a list of the names

```yaml
  list1_names: "{{ list1|
                   map(attribute='name')|
                   map('regex_replace', '^.*_(.*)_.*$', '{name: \\1}')|
                   map('from_yaml') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  list1_names:
    - name: SOMEITEM-A01
    - name: SOMEITEM-A02
    - name: SOMEITEM-A03
```

Update list1

```yaml
  list1_update: "{{ list1|zip(list1_names)|map('combine') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  list1_update:
    - {name: SOMEITEM-A01, policy: one, type: random}
    - {name: SOMEITEM-A02, policy: two, type: random}
    - {name: SOMEITEM-A03, policy: three, type: random}
```

Use the filter *unique* to remove duplicates from *list2*. Then, use the filter *difference* to remove common items

```yaml
  list3: "{{ list2|unique|difference(list1_update) }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  list3:
    - {name: SOMEITEM-A04, policy: four, type: random}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    list1: 
      - {name: aBC_SOMEITEM-A01_dEF, type: random, policy: one}
      - {name: aBC_SOMEITEM-A02_dEF, type: random, policy: two}
      - {name: aBC_SOMEITEM-A03_dEF, type: random, policy: three}

    list2: 
      - {name: SOMEITEM-A01, type: random, policy: one}
      - {name: SOMEITEM-A02, type: random, policy: two}
      - {name: SOMEITEM-A03, type: random, policy: three}
      - {name: SOMEITEM-A03, type: random, policy: three}
      - {name: SOMEITEM-A04, type: random, policy: four}

    list1_names: "{{ list1|
                      map(attribute='name')|
                      map('regex_replace', '^.*_(.*)_.*$', '{name: \\1}')|
                      map('from_yaml') }}"
    list1_update: "{{ list1|zip(list1_names)|map('combine') }}"
    list3: "{{ list2|unique|difference(list1_update) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: list1_names
    - debug:
        var: list1_update|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: list3|to_yaml
```

---

Q: ***"list2 has duplicate items. How can I find the duplicate?"***

A: Count the frequencies. For example,

```yaml
    l2_keys: "{{ list2.0.keys() }}"
    freq: "{{ list2|
              map('dict2items')|
              map('map', attribute='value')|
              map('join', ',')|
              community.general.counter }}"
    duplicates: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for k,v in freq.items() %}
      {% if v > 1 %}
      {% set arr=k.split(',') %}
      - {{ dict(l2_keys|zip(arr)) }}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  l2_keys: [name, type, policy]

  freq:
    SOMEITEM-A01,random,one: 1
    SOMEITEM-A02,random,two: 1
    SOMEITEM-A03,random,three: 2
    SOMEITEM-A04,random,four: 1

  duplicates:
    - {name: SOMEITEM-A03, policy: three, type: random}
```

---

**Custom filters**

Instead of the somewhat awkward Jinja expressions, you can write [custom filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins). Especially, when there are great Python packages available like [numpy](https://numpy.org/) and [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). For example,

```py
shell> cat plugins/filter/pandas.py
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)
__metaclass__ = type

import pandas as pd


def pandas_duplicated(d, subset=None, keep='first', idx=False):
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    d_temp = df.duplicated(subset=subset, keep=keep).to_dict()
    if idx:
        return([k for k, v in d_temp.items() if v])
    else:
        return(d_temp)


class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'pandas_duplicated': pandas_duplicated,
        }
```

```py
shell> cat plugins/filter/numpy.py
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)
__metaclass__ = type

import json
import numpy


def numpy_array_by_idx(arr, idx):
    a = numpy.array(arr)
    return json.dumps(list(a[idx]))


class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'numpy_array_by_idx': numpy_array_by_idx,
        }
```

Configure [DEFAULT_FILTER_PLUGIN_PATH](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-filter-plugin-path) the path(s) to the filters. For example,

```ini
shell> grep filter ansible.cfg
filter_plugins = $PWD/plugins/filter
```

Then the expression

```yaml
  idx: "{{ list2|pandas_duplicated(idx=true) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  idx: [3]
```

and

```yaml
  duplicates: "{{ list2|numpy_array_by_idx(idx) }}"
```

gives the duplicate item(s)

```yaml
  duplicates:
    - {name: SOMEITEM-A03, policy: three, type: random}
```

You can create a one-liner if you want to. The expression below gives the same result

```yaml
  duplicates: "{{ list2|numpy_array_by_idx(list2|pandas_duplicated(idx=true)) }}"
```

See:

- More filters [numpy.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/master/filter_plugins/numpy_filters/numpy.py)
- More filters [pandas_filters.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/master/filter_plugins/pandas_filters/pandas_filters.py)
- Examples of other [plugins](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins)

Comment: Thanks. `map('from_yaml')` was what I needed to normalize. 

What about the 2nd question to find duplicate dicts in the list? I'd like to alert the user which dict entry in list2 was duplicated. E.g

`- {name: "SOMEITEM-A03", type: "random", policy: "three"}`

Comment: I added an example.